# What is the solution for x in this right triangle using Pythagoras theorem?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

The answer is 5cm according to the book, but I couldn't get that number in several tries.

[image: Right triangle with legs measuring x and 12, and hypotenuse measuring (x+8)]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Are you having trouble writing an equation for $x$ or solving the equation?

Comment: finding value of x

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please show your work.  How far did you get?   Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
16x+64=(x+8)^2-x^2=12^2=144 \; \Rightarrow \; x=5
$$

Comment: Thank you! turns out i forgot to subtract x^2 with the another x^2